# Tags [custom-data-attribute] and [data-attributes] should be merged

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

The tags [custom-data-attribute](/questions/tagged/custom-data-attribute) and [data-attributes](/questions/tagged/data-attributes) should be merged. They are for the same topic. Note that [custom-data-attribute](/questions/tagged/custom-data-attribute) has a wiki, while [data-attributes](/questions/tagged/data-attributes) does not.

Comment: Why should they be merged? What do the tags refer to? How do you know that they mean the same thing?

Comment: Would the downvoter please explain why?

Comment: You know those comments don't actually get to anyone, right? Well, except the person who commented before (that would be me). So they mostly just serve to annoy me. Especially because you obviously haven't read the FAQ, which explains [voting on Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta).

Comment: @CodyGray Forgot it would send you notification; sorry about that. And I did know that voting on meta means agreement/disagreement, but explanations are still a courtesy.

Comment: I disagree, the explanation was already provided in the FAQ. Most likely the downvoter disagrees with your proposed tag merger. Was that really so hard to guess?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did a double take upon seeing this, because I was *sure* I'd done something like this before...

Wait. [I *have*.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146043/merge-data-attribute-into-custom-data-attribute)

You're telling me it's come up *again*?

And this time in *plural*?

*Outrageous.* I've merged them and made them synonyms now.

Comment: Seems like there are other data attributes than the HTML custom data attribute. No?

Comment: Just wait for somebody to make [tag:html5-data-attribute]...